# Security measures for an AngularJS + Firebase App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, single-page-application, firebase-security

I've built a Single Page App Review website using AngularJS and Firebase. The site allows users to view and post reviews.

I'm concerned with the security risks of having a having client-side application with no back-end like Node.js to secure the link between the front-end and the Firebase Database.

I plan on implementing Firebase rules to determine whether or not a user can post a review - but protection for things like:

- XSS attacks
- User input fields validation
- Writing to the Database

Are handled in the public client-side JavaScript files - meaning they can be tampered with.

I've looked at solutions such as [Jscrambler](https://jscrambler.com). Are there other security measures I should implement?

Comment: Firebase Database security rules protect your database from unauthorized writes. So that should cover your 3rd bullet point. But aside from that, securing a web app is a quite broad topic. Without a very specific problem (with accompanying code that illustrated/reproduces the problem), it'll be hard to give a more concrete answer.

Comment: Consider using Webtask and [webtask tokens](https://webtask.io/docs/issue_parameters) to hold secret parameters and do validation.